# When is the language said to be context free?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, programming-languages, context-free-grammar

When a language is said to be *context* free ?

Also, what is the difference between *context free language* and *context free grammar* ?

Comment: Since I see the official Wikipedia article has been copied here trice already, I guess it would help to specify how simple you want the answer to be. I can't imagine the Wikipedia explanation helps any.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia articles, they provide good explanations. There's no need for us to duplicate Wikipedia's work. If there's something you don't understand in the Wikipedia article, feel free to ask specific questions on [cs.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Context Free Language is a language (that is, a possibly infinite set of strings) which can be generated by a Context Free Grammar. In general, it is also possible to generate the exact same language with a non-context-free-grammar, but that's irrelevant: if there is a single context-free grammar which generates the language, the language is context free.

A context free grammar is a grammar in which every production has a single non-terminal on the left-hand side. It's context-free in the sense that the non-terminal in the production can be expanded without regard to the context in which it appears. Context-sensitive grammars may have multiple symbols on the left-hand side of productions, and therefore include cases in which a non-terminal can only be expanded if it appears in the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of [pumping lemma for context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages). It is a lemma that gives a property shared by all context-free languages.

Also A language (L)  is said to be a context-free language (CFL), if there exists a CFG

## G

, such that .

## L= L(G)

ie, a CFL can be generated by a Context Free Grammar.

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) says:-

> In formal language theory, a context-free language (CFL) is a language
>   generated by some context-free grammar (CFG). Different CF grammars
>   can generate the same CF language, or conversely, a given CF language
>   can be generated by different CF grammars. It is important to
>   distinguish properties of the language (intrinsic properties) from
>   properties of a particular grammar (extrinsic properties).
>
> The set of all context-free languages is identical to the set of
>   languages accepted by pushdown automata, which makes these languages
>   amenable to parsing. Indeed, given a CFG, there is a direct way to
>   produce a pushdown automaton for the grammar (and corresponding
>   language), though going the other way (producing a grammar given an
>   automaton) is not as direct.